# Remove all local bookmarks and commits from mercurial repository

Tags: mercurial, repository, commit

I'm looking for the simplest way strip all local commits (i.e. not committed in the remote repo) and remove all local bookmarks from a mercurial repository. I know I can run something like `hg bo | xargs hg strip && hg bo | xargs hg bo -d` (obviously with stripping out the commit hashes) but I've had trouble trying things like this when I have stacked commits.

Is there an easy (if a little heavy handed, maybe) way to blow away all local changes to your copy of the repository, leaving you with one that mirrors the remote repository exactly? Thanks!

Comment: BTW, plain `hg foo` will NOT work with xargs due to it's default forat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In order to strip subtree, you can strip only oldest ancestor by hand

> The strip command removes the specified changesets and all their descendants.

2. In order to get roots of not-published changesets, you can use revsets and templating. If you have single remote repo (with `default` alias) it will be just

> ```
> hg log -r "roots(outgoing())" -T "{node|short}\n"
> ```

for many remotes revset can be modified to

> ```
> roots(outgoing(PATH1) & outgoing(PATH2) ... & outgoing(PATHN))
> ```

or (with some assumtions: a) Mercurial have support for phases b) secret phase  not used c) remote repo is ordinary "publishing repo")

```
roots(draft())
```

(not pushed changesets are in draft phase by default)